# Prestashop admin panel custom filter for comma-separated column

Tags: php, filter, prestashop, backend, prestashop-1.5

here my comma separated column is shops(eg. 1,2,3,4), and with the call back i am already displaying the multiple shops names. with call back i am showing the related shop-names(values shows eg. Shop1,Shop2,Shop3,Shop4).

is there a way i can filter it with the values i am displaying.

```
$this->fields_list = array(
    'id_push' => array('title' => $this->l('ID')),
    'shops' => array('title' => $this->l('Shop(s)'),'callback' => 'getShopName','type'=>'editable')
);
```

Comment: Where you have to filter? In the list? Which version of prestashop?

Comment: this is a custom module. and ver 1.5.6.1

Comment: Is a backoffice controller?

Comment: yes admin back end controller.

Answer (score 0):

You should include a concatenated shop name field in your controller SELECT. Then you should specify `filter_key` parameter in your `shops` fieldlist field. Something like this:

```
$this->_select = ' a.`correct_field_name` AS `shopnames_custom_field`';

$this->fields_list = array(
    'id_push' => array('title' => $this->l('ID')),
    'shops' => array('title' => $this->l('Shop(s)'),'callback' => 'getShopName','type'=>'editable', 'filter_key' => 'shopnames_custom_field')
);
```

If this solution does not work you should modify `getList` function to custom filter results.

Good luck